# Como abrir un navigation drawer activity desde una empty activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Como podría hacer para abrir esta activity de navigation drawer desde una empty activity?
Tengo un login, y quiero que al iniciar sesión llegue a este activity con navigation drawer, pero me tira un error si abro lo abro con un intent.
Pero en cambio si creo un proyecto desde 0 con navigation drawer no hay ningun problema para abrirlo.

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String txtEmail = edEmail.getText().toString();
            String txtPass = edPass.getText().toString();
            if(txtEmail.isEmpty() || txtPass.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Rellene todos los campos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Boolean checkUserPass = DB.checkUserPass(txtEmail,txtPass);
                if(checkUserPass){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sesión iniciada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InicioActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error al iniciar sesión.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Cuando cambia de activity me da este error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proyectofinal/com.example.proyectofinal.InicioActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.example.proyectofinal:layout/activity_inicio: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.proyectofinal:layout/app_bar_inicio: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encuentra en el layout que carga tu Activity `InicioActivity`, este layout se indica dentro del mètodo `setContentView()` que se llama dentro de `onCreateView()`, lo que sucede aquì es que no puede inflar una clase que definiste dentro de este layout:

> Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

El problema se debe seguramente a que no has definido la dependencia para poder usar esta clase en tu proyecto, definela dentro de tu archivo `app/build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: En las dependencias tengo esto:
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

@Jorgesys

Comment: entonces si defines la dependencia, agrega activity_inicio.xml y app_bar_inicio.xml me pareces que este ùltimo puede ser el del problema